# Retaining part of the removed duplicate data

Tags: oracle

I am looking to remove duplicates from a table based on a field called "CID" (customer_Id field) BUT I need to retain a values from a row to be deleted and add it as a new field in the remaining uniqe row/entry.

EG:

CID   Color
 A12 Blue
 A12 Green
 A13 Red

Would look like this:

CID Color NewColor2
A12    Blue    Green
A13    Red

Comment: quick tip: in order to preserve spaces in your examples, you can select the text and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `{ }` (Code Sample).

Comment: Does the `NewColor2` column exist in the table?  What if there are 3 rows with the same `CID`?  How do you know whether to remove the "Green" row or to remove the "Blue" row?  Or would it be equally acceptable to have a `CID` of A12, a `Color` of Green, and a `NewColor2` of Blue?

Comment: No the NewColor2 field does not exist in the table yetc- that would have to be created during the query. It would be acceptable to remove either "Blue" or "Green" as a duplicate as long as it appears in the NewColor2.  There would not be multiple rows with the same CID AND the same color...if there is duplicate of CID then the color will be different.

Comment: Sorry about the initial example....my first time on this site.  Example corrected. Thanks Cheran.

Comment: Are there any duplicate tupels? for example two (A12, Blue)s?

Comment: And do you only want two colours. What happens if there's `A12` with teal, magenta and aubergine - blue, red and purple :-) ?

Comment: No there should not be two CIDs with the same color...A12s with Blue in color. The duplicates shoujld be removed by the values found in the field CID

Answer (score 0):

The following query, will give you maximum number of distinct colors, so you can create the required fields:

```
select max(count(distinct color))
  from MY_TABLE
 group by CID;
```

I would add a _rank field to table, so it would be much easier to distinguish records:

```
alter table MY_TABLE add (_rank number(10));

update MY_TABLE set _rank = rank() over (partition over CID order by color);

alter table MY_TABLE add constraint ukx unique (CID, _rank);
```

then execute following query for each field color2, color3, color4 ....

```
update MY_TABLE x 
   set x.color2 = 
       (select y.color 
          from MY_TABLE y
         where x.CID = y.CID
           and y._rank = 2)
 where x._rank = 1;
```

and at last:

```
delete from MY_TABLE where _rank != 1;

alter table MY_TABLE drop (_rank);
```